# Dart: classes for use as mixin and base class for constant instances

Tags: dart, constants, mixins

I have a class I want to use mostly as a base class for other classes that have constant instances, but also as a mixin class for others. Ideally, I'm after something like the following:

```dart
class Base{ 
  someMethod(){
    //do something
  }
}

class ConstantClass extends Base{
  const ConstantClass();

  anotherMethod(){
    //do something else
  }
}

class MixedClass extends NonMixinClass with Base{
  thirdMethod(){
    //a third thing
  }
}
```

The above has an error in that ConstantClass cannot have a constant constructor without calling a super-class constant constructor. However, if I add a constructor of any kind to Base(), it can't be used as a mixin.

My current workaround is to duplicate functionality in static methods, as in the following:

```dart
class Base{
  const Base();
  static someStaticMethod(Base base){
    //do something
  }

  someMethod() => Base.someStaticMethod(this);
}

class ConstantClass extends Base{
  const ConstantClass(): super();

  anotherMethod(){
    //do something else
  }
}

class BaseMixin implements Base{
  someMethod() => Base.someStaticMethod(this);
}

class MixedClass extends NonMixinClass with BaseMixin{
  thirdMethod(){
    //a third thing
  }
}
```

This isn't too bad when there's only one function in the base class, but things get pretty verbose for a complex class, and if there's a simple way of getting around the problem I'd love to keep things clean. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are plans to lift many of the mixin restrictions eventually,  but I don't know if this is in near or far future.

Answer (score 0):

I though `class ConstantClass extends Object with Base {` would do it, but the new error I get is "Constant constructor cannot be declared for a class with a mixin". So I don't see a solution here, but not using a const constructor.